# How to display the post titles on the left side of the page and show the details in the right side upon clicking the titles in WordPress

Tags: plugins

When i create a new page in the WordPress. I would like to display title of all the available Post in the left side of the page and once if i click on the specific title the details of that title should show or display right side on the same page.

Is that possible? Thank you very much for your support in advance.

I try to search some plugins but could not find any.